# negative filter in sql m:n-join query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I would like to get one random record of a table filtered by some criteria.
I have 3 tables (item, category, item_category) in a MariaDB:

The item should be in category 1 but not in category 2 and also not in category 3.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN item_category 
ON item.id = item_category.item_id
WHERE item_category.item_id NOT IN (2,3)
```

The results include item 1 because it is in both category 1 and category 2. What is my mistake and what would be  the correct sql query?

Underneath my simplified table structure:

item:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | item_1 |
| 2 | item_2 |
| 3 | item_3 |
| 4 | item_4 |

category:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | category_1 |
| 2 | category_2 |
| 3 | category_3 |

item_category:

| id | item | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your point with your critic: I provided an example of what I do, what I'm trying to achieve and what happens instead based on the SQL query I posted within the question. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Presumably the random result will always be item 2, as that is the only item which fulfills the stated criteria

Comment: The problem isn't that the result should consist of just one random item but that the filter doesn't work the way I intended

Comment: The problem then is that you haven't adequately explained the problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  item_category.item_id NOT IN (2,3) would not it be  item_category.category_id NOT IN (2,3)? Please try inner join instead of left join

```
SELECT *
FROM item 
inner JOIN item_category 
ON item.id = item_category.item_id
WHERE item_category.item_id NOT IN (2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this simple enough and logical enough?

```
SELECT item.* 
    FROM item
    WHERE     EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM ic WHERE item_id = i.item_id AND cat_id IN (1)   )
      AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM ic WHERE item_id = i.item_id AND cat_id IN (2,3) );
```

This would probably be more efficient:

```
SELECT item.* 
    FROM item
    JOIN ic USING(user_id)
    WHERE ic.cat_id = 1
      AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM ic WHERE item_id = i.item_id AND cat_id IN (2,3) );
```

Other solutions have a problem when trying to formulate "neither 2 nor 3" because it does not equate to "not 2 or not 3".